# In yellows and blacks

Tags: riddle, language

In yellows and blacks,
He often lives on racks,
He loves none but Penny.

Hint:

> a mascot

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is it [Tux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tux)?

In yellows and blacks

> He is yellow and black (also white)

He often lives on racks,

> Computer racks

He loves none but Penny.

> Penny is his "female counterpart" [according to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tux#Female_Tux_versions_in_video_games)

Comment: I thought about Tux but discounted it since white wasn't mentioned. Also, who says Tux loves Penny? I'm guessing this is the right answer, though.

Answer (score 6):

Could it be:

> [Buzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzz_(mascot)) the mascot of Georgia Institute of Technology

```
In yellows and blacks,
```

> He's a yellowjacket

```
He often lives on racks,
```

> The costume is often on clothes racks

```
From Georgia he could be,
```

> the mascot of Georgia Institute of Technology

```
He loves none but Penny.
```

> Something about BuzzCard?

Comment: This works really well for "From Georgia he could be" + the "He's not from Georgia" hint, because he's from the state of Georgia, but not the University of Georgia. Penny makes me think of Penny and Roe Stamps, who the student center is named after, but that's only tangentially related to Buzz.

Answer (score 5):

My guess:

In yellows and blacks,

> Army dress uniforms include yellow and black. 
> Their new PT uniforms are yellow and black. 
> Or their patch is yellow and black.

He often lives on racks,

> Military jargon calls beds "racks"

From Georgia he could be,

> Fort Benning, Ga is one of the Army boot camps though there are other locations.

He loves none but Penny.

> Penny is one, of the many, many words for booze in the military. 
> OR it can refer to the "Guy who knows where the Penny drops" ie. whoever knows what is actually going on. 
> As an fyi, the military jargon for girlfriend is "Suzy" or "Suzy Rottencrotch" if she's seeing Jodie.

So your a

> Soldier

Though in my case In red and blue and from San Diego I would be ;).

Answer (score 4):

My answer:

> [Pete Penguin](http://www.ysusports.com/fan_zone/mascots) the mascot of Youngstown State University

```
In yellows and blacks,
```

> The costume is mainly black (and white) with a yellow beak

```
He often lives on racks,
```

> The costume is often on clothes racks

```
From Georgia he could be,
```

> There's also a Youngstown Georgia

```
He loves none but Penny.
```

> Penny is his penguin wife.

Comment: Your answer sounds good to me.  Is there any reason you can see that having the riddle written in 1337 is useful?

Comment: @LeppyR64 I have no idea. I couldn't come up with any reason for that other than maybe to just obscure the riddle a little further.

Answer (score -1):

> Yellowjacket. They're annoyingly common around here, and frequently make their nests up underneath any eave or 'rack' they can find.
>
>  Nasty little hostile buggers -- they literally love nobody and are very, very aggressive.